# CSS conditional statement for alternating row color (start at last row?)

Tags: css, phpbb, conditional-statements

Minor cosmetic issue.. I am in the process of developing a forum based site with dynamic PHP tables that include headers and footers.  I currently have a CSS conditional statement for alternating background colors for even and odd rows in my tables.

```
<!-- IF forumrow.S_ROW_COUNT is even-->
   <li class="row" style="background-color:#536482;">
<!-- ELSE -->
   <li class="row" style="background-color:#E0EBB2;">
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

My issue is that the common footer of my tables are the same color as the even count in my conditional statement and it would look kind of weird, like it would make the footer look larger than it actually is if it were the same color as the last row, that is if the table were to end on an even numbered row.

My question is if there is anything I can add to my conditional statement to make it start at the last row of my tables? Then the last row against the footer would always be #E0EBB2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a CSS conditional statement. That is a conditional block that's part of your PHP forum's template engine, whatever it is.

Comment: Yes, I'm modifying PHPBB3's prosilver theme. I excluded what wasn't prevalent to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just the css pseudo selector `nth-last-child` and nothing more.

Try it:

```
ul li {
   background-color: #536482;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(odd) {
    background-color: #E0EBB2;
}
```

**Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/PxfZz/).**

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!  I try to stay away from CSS3 but for something as minor as background colors, I could care less =)

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to let PHP generate the styling than relying on comment conditionals. From the PHP script, you could also count the rows and start with a certain colour if even, the other one if odd. Comment conditionals are not widely or consistently supported.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm pretty fluent in html/css although I'm lacking in php quite a bit, still pretty new to php, could you post a link by any chance?